# Wcf System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.'

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, nhibernate

I'm trying to test my WCF service ıt is include methods create,update,getlist to Sql Server vs. .It works GET method on browser but i want to test POST method on Console app.So i service reference its to console app.I get this error ;

**System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.'**

*Inner Exception
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request*

**EDIT!!**

*ERROR:
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WSTester.WorkWS.IService1.GetCustomerList()
   at WSTester.WorkWS.Service1Client.GetCustomerList() in C:\Users\aykut\source\repos\Work\WSTester\Connected Services\WorkWS\Reference.cs:line 291
   at WSTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\aykut\source\repos\Work\WSTester\Program.cs:line 47*

Thanx for advice.
**This is my App.config in Console APP**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.XX:7767/Service1.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="WorkWS.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**And here is my Web.config in WebService:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;;Initial Catalog=FirstProject; User Id = aykut ; password= 1234</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="HBM_ASSEMBLY" value="BusinessEntities" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
      </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="WebService.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Meta veri bilgilerini açığa çıkarmaktan kaçınmak için, dağıtımdan önce aşağıdaki bilgileri false yapın -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- Hatalarda hata ayıklamak amacıyla özel durum ayrıntıları almak için aşağıdaki değeri true yapın.  Özel durum bilgilerini açığa çıkarmaktan kaçınmak için dağıtımdan önce false yapın -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Iesi.Collections" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**And here is the my main method;**

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Name = "dsfsfsdf";
        c.SurName="asdass";
        c.Age = 12;
        client.CreateCustomer(c);
    }
```

*EDIT!!*
**This is my Service1.svc:**

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetCustomerList")]
        public List<Customer> GetCustomerList()
        {
            CustomerFinder cm = new CustomerFinder();
            List<Customer> customerlist = cm.GetAllCustomers();
            return customerlist;
        }
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "GetCustomerByID/{id}")]
        public Customer GetCustomerByID(string id)
        {
            CustomerFinder cm = new CustomerFinder();
            Customer customer = cm.FindByID(Int32.Parse(id));
            return customer;
        }

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "CreateCustomer",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("FAIL");
            }
            CustomerManager cm = new CustomerManager();
            cm.CreateCustomer(customer);
        return customer;
        }
}
```

**This is IService:**

```
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        List<Customer> GetCustomerList();

        [OperationContract]
        Customer GetCustomerByID(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer);

        [OperationContract]
        void DeleteCustomerByID(string id);
    }

}
```

**And this is my CreateCustomer method:**

```
public class CustomerManager : BusinessComponentBase
{
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        ISession session = this.GetSession();
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                this.GetSession().Save(customer);               
                this.GetSession().Save(customer.Addresses);
                tx.Commit();

            }
            catch
            {
                tx.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return customer;
    }
```

Comment: The issue is on the server side. Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

**I find the solution.**.Problem is on CreateCustomer method. When i implement to my tables on sql server addresses can not be null and they already mapped so do not need for Save(customer.Addresses) this way;

```
    public Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        ISession session = this.GetSession();
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                this.GetSession().Save(customer);
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                tx.Rollback();
            }
        }
        return customer;
    }
```